# Help with Atmega32u4 custom PCB

Tags: pcb-design, avr, kicad, atmega32u4

I have attempted to design my own custom Atmega32u4 board, but when I assembled it it didn't show up in windows device manager. I fixed the problem where I forgot to connect VBUS to VCC with a jumper but it still doesn't show up in device manager. I have also measured all the power rails and made sure that everything got 5v. Any help would be much appreciated.  [image]

Comment: What software is running on the AVR?

Comment: I assume you want to use the DFU. Have you set the BOOTRST or HWBE fuses so it enters the Bootloader. If you don't do this then it won't start the bootloader, and will not be recognized on the USB bus.

Comment: @JackCreasey can you explain how to do this, sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: @FabianCojman Read the documentation for the device (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc7618.pdf). While the device comes with a DFU loader it is NOT enabled by default, and folks may normally program their own loader (and not replace the DFU).

Comment: _"I have attempted to design my own custom Atmega32u4 board"_ - So, where's the board layout? You show a schematic, which is great, but the board layout (and perhaps a photograph) may also help. _"... it didn't show up in windows device manager."_ - What have you done to debug this? Is the firmware on the AVR running (e.g. blinking a LED connected to a gpio)? Do you see any attempt at communication over the USB data lines with an oscilloscope? Etc...

Comment: @JackCreasey Alright thanks i think i know what i need to do now. I have to enable it via ISP.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>220 Ohms, if your schematic represents what you have on the board is too high.  You should be using ~22 Ohm for USB 2.0</strike> **edit**: As noted by below, your schematic is correct here, just interesting notation and I misread.

It looks like you are basing this off of https://github.com/Dr-Derivative/Goldfish/blob/master/doc/goldfish.pdf

You should examine the key differences here.  Notably:

- ### CC1/CC2 are not terminated
- You have unconnected VBus lines on your connector
- You have unconnected D-/D+ lines on your connector
- Your ATMega is insufficiently bypassed by capacitors on the power input.

The CC1/CC2 not being terminated is the biggest issue.  The CC lines are how USB-C determines connectivity and orientation.  Without them, your system won't attach as it doesn't know which way you've inserted the connector.

Comment: According to the schematic, those *are* 22 Ohm resistors, not 220 "HM" resistors.

Comment: Hey, you're right!  And now to get my eyes checked :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply but the cable i am using is a type a to type c and the a side is connected to the b side already in the connector i double checked this by putting probes in the connector and infact the data lines are present same goes with the vbus and ground